# How can I stop Ubuntu from playing audio from 2 interfaces at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I just loaded Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick on my home machine. The machine is running a Core2Duo E6750 on an MSI motherboard with an Nvidia GTX260-OC Graphics card.

The problem I am having as stated in the title is for some reason Ubuntu is playing audio through my headphone coming out from the computer and it is also playing the audio at the exact same time through the HDMI connection coming out of the graphics card, it has a plug to allow this.

What is going on, I have never seen this before. Most importantly of all can it be fixed so that I can sepertate the 2 interfaces, the one is a standard PC audio IO and the HDMI one is connected through the mobo's internal SPDIF.

More information can be provided if required.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? And do you know if you use ALSA or PulseAudio?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 10.10 with all recent updates, I think I am running PulseAudio. It is whatever Ubuntu uses by default.